# How to solve WCf timeout error

Tags: wcf

Referencing WCF Service and using the WCf methods throws operation timeout error. Here is my web.config:

```
<binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMembernationService"  
         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
         sendTimeout="00:10:00">
      <readerQuotas
        maxDepth="2147483647"
        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
</binding>
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: where is your web.config code??

Comment: <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMembernationService"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <readerQuotas
            maxDepth="2147483647"
            maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
            maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>

Comment: I have tried increasing executiontimeout also. Its not working.

Comment: Also show the service section (e.g. is the service using that binding?) Also show the client config (e.g. is the client using that binding?) Sometimes it doesn't & will fall back to using the defaults, which have short timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest verify that your binding section is enclosed between wsHttpBinding, bindings and system.serviceModel tags.

I think the following link can help you:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733051(v=vs.110).aspx

If this does not solve your problem, may be the timeout is set inside the source code of your service or application.